# How to add same column and split it in two on bases of creation date SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Following is the query.

```
/* Formatted on 4/7/2015 2:27:29 PM (QP5 v5.139.911.3011) */
SELECT DISTINCT
     'Dated: 01-March-2015 to  31-March-2015' AS dated,
     expm.EXPENSE_MASTER_ID,
     MAX (geo.code) AS Distributor_code,
     MAX (geo.description) AS disname,
     expm.EXPESNE_DATE,
     geo.region_description AS region,
     expm.attribute1 || '-' || MAX (expm.EXPENSE_DESCRIPTION) AS Expense,
     expt.EXPENSE_TYPE_CODE,
     MAX (expt.EXPENSE_TYPE_DESCRIPTION) AS ExpenseType,
     expc.EXPENSE_CLASS_CODE,
     MAX (expc.EXPENSE_CLASS_DESCRIPTION) AS ExpenseClass,
     MAX (expm.EXPENSE_GROUP_TYPE_CODE),
     MAX (expm.EXPENSE_GROUP_TYPE_DESC),
     SUM (expd.QTY),
     SUM (expd.RATE),
     SUM (expd.AMOUNT),
     MAX (expd.reference1) || ' / ' || MAX (expd.reference2) AS Reference

FROM dms_expense_Master expm
     INNER JOIN dms_expense_detail expd
        ON (    expm.DISTRIBUTOR_CODE = expd.DISTRIBUTOR_CODE_MASTER
            AND expm.EXPENSE_CODE = expd.expense_code_master
            AND expm.attribute1 = expd.attribute1)
     INNER JOIN dms_expense_type expt
        ON expm.EXPENSE_TYPE_ID = expt.expense_type_id
     INNER JOIN dms_expense_class expc
        ON expt.EXPENSE_CLASS_Code = expc.EXPENSE_CLASS_Code
     INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT code,
                                 description,
                                 regioncode,
                                 region_description
                   FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT
                                   EMPLOYEE_CODE AS code,
                                      EMPLOYEE_FIRST_NAME
                                   || ' '
                                   || EMPLOYEE_LAST_NAME
                                      AS description,
                                   REGION_CODE AS regioncode
                              FROM employee
                             WHERE employee_status = '0'
                            UNION
                            SELECT DISTINCT
                                   DISTRIBUTOR_CODE AS code,
                                   DISTRIBUTOR_NAME AS description,
                                   distributor_region_code AS regioncode
                              FROM distributor
                             WHERE DISTRIBUTOR_STATUS = '0') emp
                        INNER JOIN
                           region r
                        ON R.REGION_CODE = emp.regioncode
                  WHERE R.REGION_STATUS = '0') geo
        ON NVL (expd.distributor_code, expd.employee_code) = geo.code

WHERE expm.EXPESNE_DATE BETWEEN 01-March-2015 AND 31-March-2015

GROUP BY expm.EXPENSE_MASTER_ID,
     expm.DISTRIBUTOR_CODE,
     geo.region_description,
     expm.EXPESNE_DATE,
     expm.attribute1,
     expt.EXPENSE_TYPE_ID,
     expt.EXPENSE_TYPE_CODE,
     expc.EXPENSE_CLASS_ID,
     expc.EXPENSE_CLASS_CODE,
     expm.EXPENSE_GROUP_TYPE_CODE

ORDER BY expm.EXPESNE_DATE, ExpenseType
```

This is the data I get from running the query

```html
<style type="text/css">
 table.tableizer-table {
 border: 1px solid #CCC; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
} 
.tableizer-table td {
 padding: 4px;
 margin: 3px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.tableizer-table th {
 background-color: #104E8B; 
 color: #FFF;
 font-weight: bold;
}
</style><table class="tableizer-table">
<tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>Dated</th><th>EXPENSE_MASTER_ID</th><th>DISTRIBUTOR_CODE</th><th>DISNAME</th><th>EXPENSE_DATE</th><th>REGION</th><th>EXPENSE</th><th>EXPENSE_TYPE_CODE</th><th>EXPENSE_TYPE</th><th>EXPENSE_CLASS_CODE</th><th>EXPENSE_TYPE</th><th>EXPENSE_GROUP_TYPE</th><th>EXPENSE_GROUP_TYPE_DESCRIPTION</th><th>SUM(expd.QUANTITY)</th><th>SUM(expd.RATE)</th><th>SUM(expd.AMOUNT)</th><th>REFFERENCE</th></tr>
 <tr><td>Dated: 01-March-2015 to  31-March-2015</td><td>11819</td><td>3223</td><td>Aamir Rauf</td><td>2-Mar-15</td><td>Gujranwala</td><td>901-FUEL</td><td>1001</td><td>Fuel</td><td>1000</td><td>Transportation</td><td>Region</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>1</td><td>1000</td><td>1000</td><td>PETROL /</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Dated: 01-March-2015 to  31-March-2015</td><td>11800</td><td>3593</td><td>Mirza Jawad Akram Baig</td><td>2-Mar-15</td><td>Multan</td><td>901-Petty Cash Multan</td><td>1001</td><td>Fuel</td><td>1000</td><td>Transportation</td><td>Region</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>1</td><td>700</td><td>700</td><td>/</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Dated: 01-March-2015 to  31-March-2015</td><td>11794</td><td>3593</td><td>Mirza Jawad Akram Baig</td><td>2-Mar-15</td><td>Multan</td><td>896-Petty Cash Multan</td><td>4011</td><td>Gas Bill</td><td>4000</td><td>Office Administration Expense</td><td>Region</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>1</td><td>485</td><td>485</td><td>/</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Dated: 01-March-2015 to  31-March-2015</td><td>11796</td><td>3593</td><td>Mirza Jawad Akram Baig</td><td>2-Mar-15</td><td>Multan</td><td>897-Petty Cash Multan</td><td>7001</td><td>General Expenses</td><td>8000</td><td>Others</td><td>Region</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>1</td><td>160</td><td>160</td><td>/</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Dated: 01-March-2015 to  31-March-2015</td><td>11795</td><td>3593</td><td>Mirza Jawad Akram Baig</td><td>2-Mar-15</td><td>Multan</td><td>896-Petty Cash Multan</td><td>7001</td><td>General Expenses</td><td>8000</td><td>Others</td><td>Region</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>1</td><td>400</td><td>400</td><td>/</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Dated: 01-March-2015 to  31-March-2015</td><td>11935</td><td>3240</td><td>Muhammad Farrukh Waseem</td><td>2-Mar-15</td><td>Karachi A</td><td>411-Month of Mar-2015</td><td>5011</td><td>Others</td><td>5000</td><td>Repair and Maintenance</td><td>Region</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>1</td><td>3000</td><td>3000</td><td>Car Parking Charges /</td></tr>
</table>
```

now I want to add another column from same SUM (expd.AMOUNT) but showing previous month data

I have gone trough inner join but it gives error when run query
the data is coming from same table so if i use same inner join is it possible or i have to use some inline query to fetch data with different where between parameters

I was able to fetch data FROM THE FOLLOWING QUERY

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUM (expd.AMOUNT)
FROM    dms_expense_Master expm
     INNER JOIN
        dms_expense_detail expd
     ON (    expm.DISTRIBUTOR_CODE = expd.DISTRIBUTOR_CODE_MASTER
         AND expm.EXPENSE_CODE = expd.expense_code_master
         AND expm.attribute1 = expd.attribute1)
WHERE expm.EXPESNE_DATE BETWEEN '01-FEB-15' AND '28-FEB-15'
GROUP BY expm.EXPENSE_MASTER_ID,
     expm.DISTRIBUTOR_CODE,
     expm.EXPESNE_DATE,
     expm.attribute1,
     expm.EXPENSE_GROUP_TYPE_CODE
```

Now how to add this result in a column on the above query
if use inner join can i use where condition in it and add results to separate column

Comment: is this for `mysql` or `sql-server`? please use appropriate tags

Comment: This is for SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay I was able to find the solution to my problem

The solution was left outer join, it helped to put data in order
What i had done is wrote inline query to fetch required output and then passing it on the basses of reference. For now the query is  optimized and working, but will keep track on it. Query is as follows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     'Dated: 01-March-2015 to  31-March-2015' AS dated,
     expm.EXPENSE_MASTER_ID,
     MAX (geo.code) AS Distributor_code,
     MAX (geo.description) AS disname,
     expm.EXPESNE_DATE,
     geo.region_description AS region,
     expm.attribute1 || '-' || MAX (expm.EXPENSE_DESCRIPTION) AS Expense,
     expt.EXPENSE_TYPE_CODE,
     MAX (expt.EXPENSE_TYPE_DESCRIPTION) AS ExpenseType,
     expc.EXPENSE_CLASS_CODE,
     MAX (expc.EXPENSE_CLASS_DESCRIPTION) AS ExpenseClass,
     MAX (expm.EXPENSE_GROUP_TYPE_CODE),
     MAX (expm.EXPENSE_GROUP_TYPE_DESC),
     SUM (expd.QTY),
     SUM (expd.RATE),
     SUM (expd.AMOUNT) AS CURRENT_EXP,
     SUM(prev.AMOUNT) AS PREVIOUS_EXP,
     MAX (expd.reference1) || ' / ' || MAX (expd.reference2) AS Reference
FROM dms_expense_Master expm
     LEFT OUTER JOIN (   SELECT  expm.DISTRIBUTOR_CODE, expd.AMOUNT
FROM    dms_expense_Master expm
     INNER JOIN
        dms_expense_detail expd
     ON (    expm.DISTRIBUTOR_CODE = expd.DISTRIBUTOR_CODE_MASTER
         AND expm.EXPENSE_CODE = expd.expense_code_master
         AND expm.attribute1 = expd.attribute1)
   WHERE expm.EXPESNE_DATE BETWEEN '01-FEB-15' AND '28-FEB-15' ) prev
        ON  prev.DISTRIBUTOR_CODE = expm.DISTRIBUTOR_CODE
     INNER JOIN dms_expense_detail expd
        ON (    expm.DISTRIBUTOR_CODE = expd.DISTRIBUTOR_CODE_MASTER
            AND expm.EXPENSE_CODE = expd.expense_code_master
            AND expm.attribute1 = expd.attribute1)
     INNER JOIN dms_expense_type expt
        ON expm.EXPENSE_TYPE_ID = expt.expense_type_id
     INNER JOIN dms_expense_class expc
        ON expt.EXPENSE_CLASS_Code = expc.EXPENSE_CLASS_Code
     INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT code,
                                 description,
                                 regioncode,
                                 region_description
                   FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT
                                   EMPLOYEE_CODE AS code,
                                      EMPLOYEE_FIRST_NAME
                                   || ' '
                                   || EMPLOYEE_LAST_NAME
                                      AS description,
                                   REGION_CODE AS regioncode
                              FROM employee
                             WHERE employee_status = '0'
                            UNION
                            SELECT DISTINCT
                                   DISTRIBUTOR_CODE AS code,
                                   DISTRIBUTOR_NAME AS description,
                                   distributor_region_code AS regioncode
                              FROM distributor
                             WHERE DISTRIBUTOR_STATUS = '0') emp
                        INNER JOIN
                           region r
                        ON R.REGION_CODE = emp.regioncode
                  WHERE R.REGION_STATUS = '0') geo
        ON NVL (expd.distributor_code, expd.employee_code) = geo.code
   WHERE expm.EXPESNE_DATE BETWEEN '01-March-2015' AND '31-March-2015'
GROUP BY expm.EXPENSE_MASTER_ID,
     expm.DISTRIBUTOR_CODE,
     geo.region_description,
     expm.EXPESNE_DATE,
     expm.attribute1,
     expt.EXPENSE_TYPE_ID,
     expt.EXPENSE_TYPE_CODE,
     expc.EXPENSE_CLASS_ID,
     expc.EXPENSE_CLASS_CODE,
     expm.EXPENSE_GROUP_TYPE_CODE
ORDER BY expm.EXPESNE_DATE, ExpenseType
```

The results are showing previous date data of the distributor in next column
Regards

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for this, both involving a case on the month:

```
CASE
    WHEN expm.EXPESNE_DATE BETWEEN '01-FEB-2015' AND '28-FEB-2015' THEN 'Dated: 01-February-2015 to  31-February-2015'
    WHEN expm.EXPESNE_DATE BETWEEN '01-MAR-2015' AND '31-MAR-2015' THEN 'Dated: 01-March-2015 to  31-March-2015'
END
```

You can use this in directly in the GROUP BY clause, something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     **CASE
        WHEN expm.EXPESNE_DATE BETWEEN '01-FEB-2015' AND '28-FEB-2015' THEN 'Dated: 01-February-2015 to  31-February-2015'
        WHEN expm.EXPESNE_DATE BETWEEN '01-MAR-2015' AND '31-MAR-2015' THEN 'Dated: 01-March-2015 to  31-March-2015'
     END AS dated,**
     expm.EXPENSE_MASTER_ID,
     MAX (geo.code) AS Distributor_code,
     MAX (geo.description) AS disname,
     expm.EXPESNE_DATE,
     geo.region_description AS region,
     expm.attribute1 || '-' || MAX (expm.EXPENSE_DESCRIPTION) AS Expense,
     expt.EXPENSE_TYPE_CODE,
     MAX (expt.EXPENSE_TYPE_DESCRIPTION) AS ExpenseType,
     expc.EXPENSE_CLASS_CODE,
     MAX (expc.EXPENSE_CLASS_DESCRIPTION) AS ExpenseClass,
     MAX (expm.EXPENSE_GROUP_TYPE_CODE),
     MAX (expm.EXPENSE_GROUP_TYPE_DESC),
     SUM (expd.QTY),
     SUM (expd.RATE),
     SUM (expd.AMOUNT),
     MAX (expd.reference1) || ' / ' || MAX (expd.reference2) AS Reference

FROM dms_expense_Master expm
     INNER JOIN dms_expense_detail expd
        ON (    expm.DISTRIBUTOR_CODE = expd.DISTRIBUTOR_CODE_MASTER
            AND expm.EXPENSE_CODE = expd.expense_code_master
            AND expm.attribute1 = expd.attribute1)
     INNER JOIN dms_expense_type expt
        ON expm.EXPENSE_TYPE_ID = expt.expense_type_id
     INNER JOIN dms_expense_class expc
        ON expt.EXPENSE_CLASS_Code = expc.EXPENSE_CLASS_Code
     INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT code,
                                 description,
                                 regioncode,
                                 region_description
                   FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT
                                   EMPLOYEE_CODE AS code,
                                      EMPLOYEE_FIRST_NAME
                                   || ' '
                                   || EMPLOYEE_LAST_NAME
                                      AS description,
                                   REGION_CODE AS regioncode
                              FROM employee
                             WHERE employee_status = '0'
                            UNION
                            SELECT DISTINCT
                                   DISTRIBUTOR_CODE AS code,
                                   DISTRIBUTOR_NAME AS description,
                                   distributor_region_code AS regioncode
                              FROM distributor
                             WHERE DISTRIBUTOR_STATUS = '0') emp
                        INNER JOIN
                           region r
                        ON R.REGION_CODE = emp.regioncode
                  WHERE R.REGION_STATUS = '0') geo
        ON NVL (expd.distributor_code, expd.employee_code) = geo.code

**WHERE expm.EXPESNE_DATE BETWEEN '01-FEB-2015' AND '31-MAR-2015'**

GROUP BY expm.EXPENSE_MASTER_ID,
     expm.DISTRIBUTOR_CODE,
     geo.region_description,
     **--expm.EXPESNE_DATE,
     CASE
        WHEN expm.EXPESNE_DATE BETWEEN '01-FEB-2015' AND '28-FEB-2015' THEN 'Dated: 01-February-2015 to  31-February-2015'
        WHEN expm.EXPESNE_DATE BETWEEN '01-MAR-2015' AND '31-MAR-2015' THEN 'Dated: 01-March-2015 to  31-March-2015'
     END,**
     expm.attribute1,
     expt.EXPENSE_TYPE_ID,
     expt.EXPENSE_TYPE_CODE,
     expc.EXPENSE_CLASS_ID,
     expc.EXPENSE_CLASS_CODE,
     expm.EXPENSE_GROUP_TYPE_CODE
```

Or use it in a subquery.

Comment: This is good suggestion but still i am not getting what i wanted